# Is there a way to append a column name to the end of each observation within respective columns?

Tags: r

[R] I am trying to modify the format of my data frame (df) so that the column name is appended to each observation within that column within R. For example:

| Soccer_Brand | Basketball_Brand |
| --- | --- |
| Adidas | Nike |
| Nike | Under Armour |

And want to get it to look like

| Soccer_Brand | Basketball_Brand |
| --- | --- |
| Adidas_Soccer_Brand | Nike_Basketball_Brand |
| Nike_Soccer_Brand | Under_Armour_Basketball_Brand |

Im attempting a market basket analysis and need to remove column names eventually. However I will lose the information on what sport the brand belongs to without appending the column names to the observations themselves. Essentially I wont be able to tell whether a 'nike' entry belongs to soccer or basketball.

I've used Excel formulas to hack a solution thus far but want my R script to be self contained. I haven't found any solutions out there for this in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `paste` a column's name onto its contents. Just iterate through all the columns. Doing so with `lapply` allows the one-liner:

```r
df[] <- lapply(seq_along(df),\(i) paste(df[[i]], names(df)[i], sep = "_"))
```

resulting in

```r
df
#>          Soccer_Brand              Basketball_Brand
#> 1 Adidas_Soccer_Brand         Nike_Basketball_Brand
#> 2   Nike_Soccer_Brand Under Armour_Basketball_Brand
```

---

**Data from question in reproducible format**

```r
df <- data.frame(Soccer_Brand     = c("Adidas", "Nike"),
                 Basketball_Brand = c("Nike", "Under Armour"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Or using an option in `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df <- df %>% 
   mutate(across(everything(), ~ str_c(.x, cur_column(), sep = "_")))
```

-output

```
df
         Soccer_Brand              Basketball_Brand
1 Adidas_Soccer_Brand         Nike_Basketball_Brand
2   Nike_Soccer_Brand Under Armour_Basketball_Brand
```